# CSS\HTML Responsive flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have been working on developing my own webpage, and for the home page I wanted a nice looking banner with 3 tiles (1 big one left with 2 smaller ones stacked on top of eachother right). 
I could get this all to work fine, but I now noticed that on mobile devices this really gets out of proportion, and I wanted to make the 3 tiles all on top of each other when the width of the screen gets less than let's say 300px.
However, I can not seem to get this to work by looking at other questions on stackoverflow, only tiles start to disappear

[Example view of what I wish to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZiu9.png)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .hero {
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
    width: 80%
  }
  .right {
    float: left;
    width: 80%
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .hero {
    height: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.left {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1;
}
.left:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.left:hover .btnLeft {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.one {
  height: 175px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/380x260');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 80%;
}
.one:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.one:hover .btnTop {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.two {
  height: 175px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/380x260');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 50%;
}
.two:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.two:hover .btnBot {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.btnLeft {
  margin-top: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btnTop {
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btnBot {
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="left" >
        <div class="btnLeft">Option 1</div>
    </a>
  <div class="right">
       <a href="http://example.com" class="one" >
            <div class="btnTop">Option 2</div>
        </a>
      <a href="http://example.com" class="two" >
            <div class="btnBot">Option 3</div>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know floats don't work in flexbox...right?

Comment: `flex-direction: column` on `.hero`, then clean up styles by negating floats, and adjusting widths accordingly.

Comment: No I did not, Thank you Paulie_D
Also thank you UncaughtTypeError, they now show up under each other I will just need to adjust widths/heights

Comment: Why bother with responsive for screen sizes below 320px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy effect to achieve using flexbox. On your smallest size screens give the `.hero` container a property of `flex-direction:column` to have them stack vertically. Once you hit your bigger breakpoint, change this to `flex-direction:row`.

Also, it's worthwhile to note that you don't need to add a `float` property to the `.left` and `.right` containers as this isn't how flexbox functions.

For a pretty in depth look of how flexbox works check out [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .hero {
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .hero {
    height: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction:row;
  }
}

.left {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1200');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1;
}
.left:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.left:hover .btnLeft {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.one {
  height: 175px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/380x260');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 80%;
}
.one:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.one:hover .btnTop {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.two {
  height: 175px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/380x260');
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 50%;
}
.two:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.two:hover .btnBot {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.btnLeft {
  margin-top: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btnTop {
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.btnBot {
  margin-top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="left" >
        <div class="btnLeft">Option 1</div>
    </a>
  <div class="right">
       <a href="http://example.com" class="one" >
            <div class="btnTop">Option 2</div>
        </a>
      <a href="http://example.com" class="two" >
            <div class="btnBot">Option 3</div>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```